# Does mesibo support group calling in Android and iOS sdks?

Tags: android, ios, sdk, video-conferencing, mesibo

We have chosen mesibo for enabling voice/video calling in our app. We must have video conferencing enabled for all our platforms. We have implemented group calling in Webapp and tested it. We wish to have to synced across our android and iOS clients too.

We could not find any documentation regarding that in mesibo Docs. Anyone to shed some light on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can request beta access. It will be available publicly by end of the month along with the source code.

Comment: Thanks for the input. How can one request for beta?

Comment: It is already part of public APIs except for UI and the documentation. Possibly you can directly contact.